# Proxy Model Customization

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I have proxy models for related types. The problem is ListView and DetailView connection.

Courses has all types of course, each course must have related type's URL.

Here is full structure of my sample code, ( models, views, urls, template)

```
#models.py
COURSE_TYPES = (
    ('a', 'Appetizer'),
    ('s', 'Soup and Salad'),
    ('m', 'Main Course'),
    ('d', 'Dessert')
)


class Course(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=COURSE_TYPES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('course', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
         
class AppetizerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(AppetizerManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            type='a')
      
class MainManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MainManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            type='m')
      
class Appetizer(Course):
    objects = AppetizerManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True  
        
class Main(Course):
    objects = MainManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        

#views.py
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'courses.html'
    
class AppetizerDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Appetizer
    template_name = 'appetizer_detail.html'

class MainDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Main
    template_name = 'main_detail.html'

    
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('courses/', views.CourseListView.as_view(), name='courses'),
    path('appetizer/<slug:slug>/', views.AppetizerDetailView.as_view(), name='appetizer'),
    path('main/<slug:slug>/', views.MainDetailView.as_view(), name='main'),
    ]


#courses.html
<h1>Courses</h1>
{% for course in object_list %}
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}">{{ course.name }}</a></li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I edit my code for this purpose properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `get_absolute_url` method on the base model `Course` in this way:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        
        # this can be more pythonic, using a dictionary perhaps
        if self.type == 'a':
           viewname = "appetizer"
        elif self.type == 'm':
           viewname = "main"
        # ...
        # continue with other proxy models...
        # ...
        return reverse(viewname, kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
```

Of course this create some coupling between the base class and the subclasses.

Comment: My original solution proposed doesn't work, because all the instances in courses.html are of type Course, I will edit my answer with other alternative.